# Coefficient of $(1+x+x^2)^n$

Tags: binomial-theorem

[image]

I presumed that $a_n$ in the second part is a typo error hence I modified the question

The question is as follow

If  ${\left( {1 + x + {x^2}} \right)^n} = {a_0} + {a_1}x + {a_2}{x^2} + .. + {a_{2n - 1}}{x^{2n - 1}} + {a_{2n}}{x^{2n}}$ then ${\left( {{a_0} + {a_1} + {a_2} + ... + {a_n}} \right)^3} - {\left( {{a_{n + 1}} + .. + {a_{2n - 1}} + {a_{2n}}} \right)^3}$ is (where $n\in N$)

(A) $0$

(B) $\frac{3^n-1}{2}$

(C) $\frac{9^n+1}{2}$

(D) $\frac{9^n-1}{2}$

My approach is as follow

Put x=1, ${3^n} = {a_0} + {a_1} + {a_2} + .. + {a_{2n - 1}} + {a_{2n}} = T + U$

$T = \left( {{a_0} + {a_1} + {a_2} + ... + {a_n}} \right)\& U = \left( {{a_{n + 1}} + .. + {a_{2n - 1}} + {a_{2n}}} \right)$

$G = {\left( {{a_0} + {a_1} + {a_2} + ... + {a_n}} \right)^3} - {\left( {{a_{n + 1}} + .. + {a_{2n - 1}} + {a_{2n}}} \right)^3} = {T^3} - {U^3}$

$G = \left( {T - U} \right)\left( {{T^2} + {U^2} + UT} \right) = \left( {T - U} \right)\left( {{{\left( {T + U} \right)}^2} - UT} \right) = \left( {T - U} \right)\left( {{3^{2n}} - UT} \right) = \left( {T - U} \right)\left( {{9^n} - UT} \right)$

${\left( {1 + x + {x^2}} \right)^n} = {\left( {1 + X} \right)^n} = \sum\limits_{r = 0}^n {{}^n{C_r}{X^r}}  = \sum\limits_{r = 0}^n {{}^n{C_r}{{\left( {x + {x^2}} \right)}^r}}  = \sum\limits_{r = 0}^n {{}^n{C_r}.{x^r}{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^r}}  = \sum\limits_{r = 0}^n {{}^n{C_r}.{x^r}\sum\limits_{g = 0}^r {{}^r{C_g}.{x^g}} } $

The solution is given as "Equidistant terms from beginning and end have the same values. Hence $a_0=a_{2n}$ &$a_1=a_{2n-1}$ "

Hence T=U, but how do I prove from the above binomial theorem but getting the general term

Comment: Hint: $$
 x^{2n}p_n \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) = p_n (x)
$$ where $p_n (x) = (1 + x + x^2 )^n$. Btw, do you subtract $(a_{n+1}+\ldots)^3$ or $(a_n+\ldots)^3$? The picture and your text differs in this regard.

Comment: I presume that the picture is a typo error hence I modified the question. These type of error do occur in the question frequently

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: @Luna 145 I took it from the old sample paper of JEE Advanced of a coaching institute, I took the screenshot and put it after omitting the coaching name. This may be the mistake of an operator which went unnoticed, I encountered these type of typo mistake in papers occasionally

Comment: Since all four options give different values for $n=1$ one can check the answer by putting $n=1$ where $a_0=a_1=a_2=1$. I wonder if this is a good fit for multiple choice type questions.

Comment: Also it appears that the question in image is correct and has no typo and the right answer is $0$ (use hint by @Gary). With your version in text the answer comes out to be $7$ in case of $n=1$ and does not match any option.